# Docket numbers of CIPs with electronic filing

Tags: continuation-in-part, docket

As a practical matter, is it better to use the same docket number with electronic filings for CIPs of a parent application, or different ones?

Answer (score 1):

A docket  number is just a way for someone who files many many applications to refer to them in their own database.  Some practitioners might use the number if the parent with “-CIP” appended. A docket number might be a meaningless serialized number or might have the applicant’s last name or company name - or anything else or just be blank.